# Setting Screen.MousePointer to HourGlass has no effect on startup

Tags: vb6

I am fixing up an old VB6 app that has a significant amount of work in the Form_Load event.  As a result, it takes several seconds for the app to actually appear after the user double-clicks it.

I tried setting Screen.MousePointer = vbHourGlass at the top of Form_Load, but it has no effect.

I've also tried adding DoEvents and Me.Refresh, also to no avail.  As a result of this, the user has no indication that anything is going on during this time.

What can I do to show the hourglass when the user double-clicks on the app?

Comment: I don't think the hourglass icon will appear until the form is displayed. You might have to consider moving the heavy stuff from form load to the paint event.

Comment: A Me.Show before the work starts will show the form. Another alternative would be a splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Before call form, set screen.mousepointer=11

```
screen.mousepointer=11
myform.show
screen.mousepointer=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the form to load, you can't do any GUI stuff until that's happened.  Use a timer to run your initilising code and show the mouse as an hourglass while this is going on, or a splash screen with a progress bar.

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/multiple-form-splash-screen-tutorial